# how to write data to a MIDI device

Tags: c#, midi

I would like to write a peer to peer application to allow transfer of MIDI data to allow musicians to jam remotely. How can I detect the MIDI interface devices?

Comment: Which OS and MIDI API do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of [MIDI.NET](http://midinet.codeplex.com/). Check it out, it will do most (if not all) the common tasks for working with MIDI.

Hope it helps.